# AIX process stack watermark

Tags: aix, stack

Does exist any tool/command for checking the maximum that a process stack has  used?
I need that to  tune the stack size configuration for a program.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of stack is 256MB (per thread). [Here](http://publibn.boulder.ibm.com/doc_link/en_US/a_doc_lib/aixprggd/genprogc/thread_quick_ref.htm#HDRD3A44BC990MANU) you can find official IBM documentation about this:

> Limits and Default Values
>
> The threads library has some implementation-dependent limits and
>   default values. These limits and default values can be retrieved by
>   symbolic constants to enhance the portability of programs.
>
> Maximum Number of Threads per Process
>
> The maximum number of threads per process is 512. The maximum number
>   of threads can be retrieved at compilation time using the
>   PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX symbolic constant defined in the pthread.h header
>   file.
>
> Minimum Stack Size
>
> The minimum stack size for a thread is 96KB. It is also the default
>   stack size. This number can be retrieved at compilation time using the
>   PTHREAD_STACK_MIN symbolic constant defined in the pthread.h header
>   file.
>
> Note that the maximum stack size is 256MB, the size of a segment. This
>   limit is indicated by the PTHREAD_STACK_MAX symbolic constant in the
>   pthread.h header file.

Also [check](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/ulimit.htm) per user `ulimit` stack size (which is in kb)